# cpp-netlib request with uri::uri

Tags: c++, cpp-netlib

I'm using the cpp-netlib version 0.11 with boost 1.55 and want to create a request object with these lines:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/network/protocol/http/client.hpp>
#include <boost/network/uri.hpp>
#include <boost/network/uri/uri_io.hpp>

using namespace boost::network;
typedef http::basic_client< http::tags::http_default_8bit_tcp_resolve ,1,1> httpClient;

int main() {
   uri::uri url = std::string("http://www.abcs.de/");

   httpClient::request req;
   req << header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

   req << url; // THIS LINE DOESN'T COMPILE
}
```

If I read the documentation ([here](http://cpp-netlib.org/0.11.0/reference/http_request.html)) right, that line to set the request url should work, but I only get

```
/usr/local/include/boost/network/protocol/http/request.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::network::http::basic_request<Tag>& boost::network::http::operator<<(boost::network::http::basic_request<Tag>&, const Directive&) [with Tag = boost::network::http::tags::http_default_8bit_tcp_resolve; Directive = boost::network::uri::uri]’:
src/receiver.h:33:11:   required from here
/usr/local/include/boost/network/protocol/http/request.hpp:71:26: error: no match for call to ‘(const boost::network::uri::uri) (boost::network::http::basic_request<boost::network::http::tags::http_default_8bit_tcp_resolve>&)’
         directive(message);
```

Comment: can you post a SSCCE?

Comment: http://codepad.org/6Z5tg2QV link against boost

Comment: @Roby, since you've found the solution to your problem, please add it as an answer to your question (and accept it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To httpClient::request object has a member method to set the url
`req.uri( url )` works