# Boost network not in standard boost install

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

Have recently become a great boost fan !!

But sometime components seem to be hidden.

eg I see example code on this site with:

```
#include <boost/network/uri.hpp>
```

etc

But my 1.55 boost install does not have a network folder.
What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Where did you see that example code? Can you link to it?

Comment: http://cpp-netlib.org/0.11.0/in_depth/uri.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179628/cpp-netlib-request-with-uriuri

Comment: Good question. You might want to [ask their developers](http://cpp-netlib.org/0.11.1/getting_started.html#reporting-issues-getting-support).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the fact that cpp-netlib is not an accepted Boost C++ Library ([current Boost C++ Libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/)). And further it's not even in the [review schedule](http://www.boost.org/community/review_schedule.html). So it's not going to be a Boost C++ Library for some time.

Answer (score 1):

For those who may come down the same path ...

boost/network is not part of the standard boost release.
It is a candidate which may at some time become part of the boost distribution.

Sources/Docs etc for boost/network can be found at:
http://cpp-netlib.org/

Acknowledgement to GrafikRobot for pointing the way.